# Looking for an E2EE protocol

Tags: encryption, protocol-design

I'm working on an application that allows people to share different types of data with other people that are in the same group. Group limit is 16 people. Logic behind it is very similar to group chats.

This application would greatly benefit from an end-to-end encryption to encrypt some of the information. I'm currently looking into E2EE to understand if it's a good fit for this project and would love to hear some thoughts

Key considerations:

1. Users should be able to send data to multiple recipients
2. Users should be able to join a group by entering an invitation code
3. Users should be able to access historic data

What I'm looking for is a simple protocol that could work for this project, preferably something that isn't overly complicated to implement. We have a team of experienced developers, but none have previously worked with E2EE.

Comment: Are you thinking of a peer-to-peer or client/server structure?